# Which is faster (mask >> i & 1) or (mask & 1 << i)?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

In my code I must choose one of this two expressions (where mask and i non constant integer numbers `-1 < i < (sizeof(int) << 3) + 1`). I don't think that this will make preformance of my programm better or worse, but it is very interesting for me. Do you know which is better and why?

Comment: Why not try both and compare? (I am assuming the two expressions are equivalent for your use case)

Comment: This looks very much like a homework/exam question to me.

Comment: Can you clarify what "mask" and "i" are?

Comment: Those expressions don't do the same thing.  So who cares if one is faster than the other? `(mask >> i & 1)`  shifts mask right 0 or 1 bits.  `(mask & 1 << i)` shifts the rightmost bit of mask to the left i times.  You need to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Adrian the question not about what this expresions do :) this is just funny question. Take it easy.

Comment: Usually, when someone asks which of two options are faster, it's because they're trying to choose which one to use.  If they do different things, then who cares which is faster?

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy In this case they do the same.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan:  For example, given `mask = 5` and `i = 2`:  `(mask >> i & 1)` yields 1.   `(mask & 1 << i)` yields 4.  Why do you care which is faster?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. I'm going to use this expressions as condition of if operator (i.e. their bool values) in in this meaning they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C expressions cannot be "faster" or "slower", because CPU cannot evaluate them directly.

Which one is "faster" depends on the machine code your compiler will be able to generate for these two expressions. If your compiler is smart enough to realize that in your context both do the same thing (e.g. you simply compare the result with zero), it will probably generate the same code for both variants, meaning that they will be equally fast. In such case it is quite possible that the generated machine code will not even remotely resemble the sequence of operations in the original expression (i.e. no shift and/or no bitwise-and). If what you are trying to do here is just test the value of one bit, then there are other ways to do it besides the shift-and-bitwise-and combination. And many of those "other ways" are not expressible in C. You can't use them in C, while the compiler can use them in machine code.

For example, the x86 CPU has a dedicated bit-test instruction `BT` that extracts the value of a specific bit by its number. So a smart compiler might simply generate something like

```
MOV eax, i
BT  mask, eax
...
```

for both of your expressions (assuming it is more efficient, of which I'm not sure).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, whenever you find yourself asking "which is faster", your first reaction should be to profile, measure and find out for yourself.

Second of all, this is such a tiny calculation, that it almost certainly has no bearing on the performance of your application.

Third, the two are most likely identical in performance.

Comment: +1 Agree, but usually my thought processes work with the order of the first two paragraphs reversed.

Comment: 1.Profiling this in different boxes with differnt OSes and getting some result I can't be sure that my result is correct one, but here can be a persons[s] who can answer to question more detailed. 2.I know that this wouldn't make performance of the application better or worse, this is just for interest. 3.It seems yes :)

Answer (score 3):

Use either one and let your compiler optimize it however it likes.

Answer (score 2):

If "i" is a compile-time constant, then the second would execute fewer instructions -- the 1 << i would be computed at compile time. Otherwise I'd imagine they'd be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Depends entirely on where the values `mask` and `i` come from, and the architecture on which the program is running.  There's also nothing to stop the compiler from transforming one into the other in situations where they are actually equivalent.

In short, not worth worrying about unless you have a trace showing that this is an appreciable fraction of total execution time.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that either will be faster. If you are really curious, compile a simple program that does both, disassemble, and see what instructions are generated.

Here is how to do that:

```
gcc -O0 -g main.c -o main
objdump -d main | less
```

Comment: It's easier to just use the `-S` flag in GCC. And since we're looking at "after the compiler has optimized at least a little", presumably, you should be using `-O2`

Comment: @Seth Thanks, I forgot about `-S`. As for `-O0` vs. `-O2`, it depends on what you're looking for. If you do `-O2` and find that they are the same, you could do `-O0` and see if the optimizer was doing extra work in one case or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could examine the assembly output and then look-up how many clock cycles each instruction takes.

But in 99.9999999 percent of programs, it won't make a lick of difference.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 expressions are not logically equivalent, performance is not your concern!

If performance was your concern, write a loop to do 10 million of each and measure.

EDIT: You edited the question after my response ... so please ignore my answer as the constraints change things.

Comment: I answered the question before you added the constraint. If you try with mask = 0xff and i=6, you'll find they are far from equal ;-)

Comment: 10 million times isn't even close to what you need to get a timing, much less see any difference. That's why the question is silly!